# Jboss EAP 7 Deployment failed - "{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"OptionsManagementREST.war\\\"

Tags: java, spring, jboss-eap-7

My project runs in production on **JBoss EAP 6**.

This **OptionsManagementREST.war** is deployed in **JBoss EAP 6** but now we are upgrading to **EAP 7**. I'm getting this error when I deploy the war file in **JBoss EAP 7** local.

The project structure would be:

1. OptionsManagement.jar
2. OptionsManagementREST.war

**OptionsManagement.jar** gets deployed first since **OptionsManagementREST.war**
has a dependency on **OptionsManagement.jar**, but for some reason on **JBoss EAP 7** the **OptionsManagementREST.war** deployment is failing and giving this error:

> "{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" =>
>   {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\"OptionsManagementREST.war\\".WeldStartService\"
>   => \"Failed to start service
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a
>   persistence unit named '' in deployment OptionsManagementREST.war for
>   injection point protected javax.persistence.EntityManager
>   wf.wbr.investments.optionsmanagement.dao.DaoRoot.emOptions\"}}"

Where do I need to make changes in order to deploy successfully to EAP7?

Comment: Have you tried adding this jar as dependency to jboss-deployment-structure.xml explicitly?